# FFmpeg - Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory

Tags: usb, webcam, ffmpeg, gphoto2

I have a Nikon D7000 which is supported by gphoto2 and can successfully take a photo.

However I cannot get this camera to work as a webcam as I thought I would be able to. Please see below:

```bsh
hutber@hutber:~$ gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
ffmpeg version N-49161-g50e194e6e1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
[mjpeg @ 0x7389940] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x426, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> rawvideo (native))
[swscaler @ 0x73b4040] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x7392700] Unable to open V4L2 device '/dev/video2'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

More information:

```bsh
hutber@hutber:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
HD Pro Webcam C920 (usb-0000:05:00.0-1.2.3):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

Comment: your vlc command lines calls `/dev/video7` and `v4l2-ctl` list output gives you `/dev/video2`... What you think ?

Comment: Thanks @cmak.fr for coming back to me. Thing is, /dev/video2 is not a real camera. I will reset my machine and see if it is still there, but I do have 2 physical webcams plugged in too, which are normally at video1 & `video2`

Comment: I reset my machine and now things are back to how you would expect.

Comment: *"now things are back to how you would expect"* Does that mean you solved the issue?

Comment: No sorry, I reset the machine and now `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` displays my two webcams